# Run Compiled Java Program Just Says Complete

Tags: java, compilation

I made a java program that accepts a user input, but when running it in JGrasp after finishing the compile it just says "operation complete" and doesn't let me input anything or display any print text that I added in the code.

```
/*
 * The file name of your program, Assign_1.java
 *  
 * TCSS 143 – January 10th, 2015
 * Assignment 1  
 */

 import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
 * This program allows 5 town populations to be entered then converted
 * to stars based on each 1000.
 *
 * @author Thejai Riem
 * @version 1/10/15
 */

 public class Assign_1 {

   /**
   * For town1-5 variable for population # that changes later
   */

   public static int town1;
   public static int town2;
   public static int town3;
   public static int town4;
   public static int town5;

   public static void main(String[] theArgs) {
   }

   /**
   * Gets population from user input of the 5 towns.
   *
   * @param theArgs is used for user input to scanner
   */

   public static void getPopulation(String[] theArgs) {
      Scanner population = new Scanner(System.in); // Keyboard input
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 1: ");
      town1 = population.nextInt(); // Asks input for town population
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 2: ");
      town2 = population.nextInt(); // Changes town(#) to user input
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 3: ");
      town3 = population.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 4: ");
      town4 = population.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 5: ");
      town5 = population.nextInt();
   } 

   /**
   * Draws population one * for 1000 people
   *
   * @param theArgs is used for string output
   */

   public static void drawPopulationBar(String[] theArgs) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("POPULATION GRAPH:");
      System.out.println("Town 1: " + town1 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 2: " + town2 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 3: " + town3 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 4: " + town4 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 5: " + town5 / 1000);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't ask for input is that you're never routing to that section of the code. Note that all Java applications run by calling a `main` method. Notice that yours is empty. I think what you want is probably something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign_1 {

   /**
   * For town1-5 variable for population # that changes later
   */

   public static int town1;
   public static int town2;
   public static int town3;
   public static int town4;
   public static int town5;

   public static void main(String[] theArgs) {
       getPopulation(theArgs);
       drawPopulationBar(theArgs);
   }

   /**
   * Gets population from user input of the 5 towns.
   *
   * @param theArgs is used for user input to scanner
   */

   public static void getPopulation(String[] theArgs) {
      Scanner population = new Scanner(System.in); // Keyboard input
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 1: ");
      town1 = population.nextInt(); // Asks input for town population
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 2: ");
      town2 = population.nextInt(); // Changes town(#) to user input
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 3: ");
      town3 = population.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 4: ");
      town4 = population.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the population of town 5: ");
      town5 = population.nextInt();
   } 

   /**
   * Draws population one * for 1000 people
   *
   * @param theArgs is used for string output
   */

   public static void drawPopulationBar(String[] theArgs) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("POPULATION GRAPH:");
      System.out.println("Town 1: " + town1 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 2: " + town2 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 3: " + town3 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 4: " + town4 / 1000);
      System.out.println("Town 5: " + town5 / 1000);
   } 
 }
```

I also see that you're not actually using any of the command line arguments (any command line arguments get populated into the string array parameter in the main method invocation). So, you can probably remove those parameters from your other two methods (but you MUST leave it in the main method even if it's not being used since it is part of the signature that java expects).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because you didn't fill out the main method of the program.

Comment: Lol. Plain and simple.